# My Lenovo S12 laptop (Intel atom) is taking a very, very long time to boot. Can I fix this?

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, lenovo

Basically it will not boot without holding down the power key.  It has taken as long as 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fix in [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+source/linux/+bug/577660) and [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132), based on the idea that the Intel atom CPU is used by both computers.

Basically, the `/etc/default/grub` is edited to add two kernel options to the Linux Default command line.

- Note: These instructions are long, but it's really simple and should not take very long.

Open a terminal (dash, type in `terminal`, … )

- Note: If you prefer a GUI editor like Gnome Text Editor, see the note at the bottom.

Type in the terminal **sudo nano -B /etc/default/grub** and your password if asked…

```
user@YourComputer:~$ sudo nano -B /etc/default/grub
```

and the **nano** editor will open, thus (for mine)...

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

#boot previous booted system by default
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

Using the arrow keys. move the cursor down to the line

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` and then to the last ", *i.e.* (`…sh"`)

Then type in a space and **nomodeset nohz=off** so it now looks like this.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset nohz=off"
```

Then type in **Ctrl-O**, the **Enter key** to save, and then **Ctrl-X** to exit **nano**.

**Important last step**

Now you have to run update-grub to update the system generated grub.cfg file in the /boot/grub directory.

Type into your computer **sudo update-grub** and your password if asked…

```
me@myS12:~$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-12-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-12-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Microsoft Windows XP Home Edition on /dev/sda1
done
```

Now the boot should be **much** shorter.

**Notes on nano**

**nano** is especally easy to use in the terminal.  Move around with the arrow keys.  Type in you addtions, delete the unwanted.

The " -B" (or " --backup") option backs up the previous version of it to the current filename suffixed with a ~.  Very handy in case of the dreaded ***Fat pfinger effect***.

When you are though, **Crtl-O** will allow you to save your edits by hitting **Enter**.
Closing nano without saving, **Ctrl-X**
These and other options are shown at the bottom of the terminal screen with the ^ indicating **Ctrl**

```
^G Get Help    ^O WriteOut    ^R Read File   ^Y Prev Page   ^K Cut Text    ^C Cur Pos
^X Exit        ^J Justify     ^W Where Is    ^V Next Page   ^U UnCut Text  ^T To Spell
```

**Notes about nano, sudoeditor, and other editors.**

Some in the Ubuntu community suggest **sudoedit** instead of **nano**.  I recommend **nano** (which is the default sudoedit editor in later distributions of Ubuntu) instead of **sudoedit** because the default can be overridden in non-obvious ways (unless you are an administrator).  **sudoedit** is safer in that it automatically saves a backup copy of the edited file, but the "`-B`" command line option in **nano** does the same thing.  **nano** is safer than other editors like **vi** or **emacs** because it doesn't have scary shell escapes.

If you prefer not to use the **nano** editor and prefer the Gnome Text Editor, instead of **sudo nano -B** use **gksu gedit**.  I generally do this for large files, and `/etc/default/grub` could easily be considered a large file.  Thus type in **gksu gedit /etc/default/grub** instead of **sudo nano -B /etc/default/grub**.  Note that the Gnome text editor does not automatically make a backup!