# How can I speed up boot it is unresponsive for a long time after the Desktop is presented?

Tags: 11.10, installation, boot, mouse, laptop

My Lenovo S12 (Intel Atom) laptop **was** taking a very long time to boot, and I found the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84357/my-lenovo-s12-laptop-intel-atom-is-taking-a-very-very-long-time-to-boot-can).

After that fix, it would boot quickly, but for a long time after the Desktop was presented, the mousepad and key board would not respond.  So long at first I thought the system was broken.

What could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there were six swap partitions on my little Lenovo.  I found the fix [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85408/why-are-there-multiple-6-swap-partitions-after-ubuntu-clean-install).